# .so not copied to output folder

Tags: .net, linux, build, nuget-package

I have a project that get a nuget dependancy, in this dependency, I have two files, a .dll and a .so.

After a dotnet build command the dependency is correctly downloaded but the .dll is copied into the bin folder but the .so is not.

I am working on linux

If you have any idea it would be great.

Thank you for your time,
Regards

Comment: .so files are usually put under a lib directory.

Comment: "but the .dll is copied into the bin folder but the .so is not" is quite normal. Which NuGet package? Its authors should have documentation on that.

Comment: An update. When I copy the .so from .nuget folder manually to /lib/ it is working. So my question is  :  "who" is in charge of putting the .so somewhere its dependency can find it, ie in /lib/  ? I don't think that this should be done manually